# Calculating volume of a revolved surface in Python

Tags: python, numpy, calculus

I have the following curve:

[image]

The curve is defined by a set of data points.

How can I calculate the volume that will be enclosed by this curve if it is rotated by 360 degrees about the  horizontal axis?

I can calculate the area underneath the curve using numerical integration, with eg `np.trapz`, but am unsure of what to do next.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your function `f(x)`, you want to calculate the [volume of revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution) about the `x`-axis.

This is given by integrating `f(x)*f(x)`, i.e. the function `f(x)`-squared, using `np.trapz` or any other integration method, and then multiplying by the constant pi (which is built in to NumPy as `np.pi`).

---

The intuition for this lies in the formula for calculating the area of a circle from its radius: `pi * r**2`.

The solid formed by rotating the curve 360 degrees about the `x`-axis is composed of infinitesimally thin disks at each point along the `x`-axis. Each disk has radius `f(x)`. The area of the face of each disk is therefore `pi * f(x)**2`.

Integrating along the `x`-axis sums the volumes of the infinitesimally thin disks and calculates the volume of the solid.

Comment: What would be the approach to calculate the surface area of the revolution?

Comment: @Jonny - Calculating the [surface area of revolution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SurfaceofRevolution.html) is a little more involved: differentiate `f(x)`, square it, add one, take the square root of that, multiply by `f(x)*2*pi` and integrate. I don't know if there's any built in function in the NumPy/SciPy stack, but the link should explain the steps in more detail.